# Wordpress - Fatal error: Cannot redeclare check_password_reset_key()

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on this wordpress site that was built by another developer, I managed to fix all the issues except for one. I have a plugin called wp-login and the plugin description:

---

*This is plugin will create a custom login, registration, and lost password page automatically inserted into your current activated theme. This plugin will override the 'wp-login.php' file. This is the only login plugin that utilizes the WordPress login code, so you know it works properly.*

---

My problem is when I goto the login page or register page, I get this error:

> **Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare check_password_reset_key() (previously declared in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas10_data01/22/2707722/html/wp-includes/user.php:2251) in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas10_data01/22/2707722/html/wp-content/plugins/wp-login/wp-login_modified.php on line 238

Here is the function inside that file:

```
/**
 * Retrieves a user row based on password reset key and login
 *
 * @uses $wpdb WordPress Database object
 *
 * @param string $key Hash to validate sending user's password
 * @param string $login The user login
 *
 * @return object|WP_Error
 */
function check_password_reset_key($key, $login) {
        global $wpdb;

        $key = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/i', '', $key);

        if ( empty( $key ) || !is_string( $key ) )
                return new WP_Error('invalid_key', __('Invalid key'));

        if ( empty($login) || !is_string($login) )
                return new WP_Error('invalid_key', __('Invalid key'));

        $user = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_activation_key = %s AND user_login = %s", $key, $login));

        if ( empty( $user ) )
                return new WP_Error('invalid_key', __('Invalid key'));

        return $user;
}
```

Does anyone know of any fixes? If I remove the plugin, the custom login and registration page are not applied.

I noticed the plugin says `This plugin will override the 'wp-login.php' file.`

Could this have to do with my `.htaccess` file?

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: What's the point of re-declaring that function in the plugin at all?

Comment: Are you saying, try to remove that function and see what happens?

Comment: You can probably do a quick fix to the problem by wrapping the function in something like: `if(!function_exists('check_password_reset_key')) { function code here... }`

Comment: Although, then WP may then not use your custom `check_password_reset_key()` version of the function. I am not 100% familiar with that kind of level of development for Wordpress, but have you looked online to see how you properly overwrite the native `check_password_reset_key()` function (or if you even can)?

Comment: Wordpress being several years old, is procedural based - a plugin that breaks that bad is not a plugin I would use. If its something custom made then you might be in for a mess.  Wordpress is not designed so you can overwrite it's core functions.